# how to find generic datatype size in JAVA?

Tags: java

I have tried `T.SIZE/8` for this question, but gives me an error.

and I have also tried `Integer.Size` this gives me an correct solution `4 bytes`.

so how can I find SIZE for Generic datatype T in JAVA?

MY PROGRAM:

```
class A<T> {
  T a;
  T b;
  A(T a, T b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  void s() {
    System.out.print("size in byte is "+(T.SIZE/8)+"bytes");
  }
}

class Demo {
  static public void main(String a[]) {
    A<Integer> ob = new A<Integer>(10, 20);
    ob.s();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't, because of type erasure.

Comment: This has nothing to do with type erasure, in Java it would have to be something dynamic anyway because the compiler cannot know!

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: you can't.
It is up to the VM how fields are ordered and aligned, thus the size is dependent on the VM implementation and configuration. However, you can attach a native agent using the Java Virtual Machine Tool Interface (JVMTI) to query the size of an object. However, this might be a little overpowered in your case and worth another question if you really need to.

A dirty hack: You may also "guess it" based on internal knowledge what the VM usually does. Every data type that is 4 bytes or less always takes up 4 bytes, every other data type (double, long) take up 8 bytes, and pointers take up 4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture. The object header takes up 16 bytes. Using reflection you can lookup your fields and count yourself. However, there are a lot of things that might mess your manual computation up, e.g., compressed oops might make pointers on 64 bit machines only 32 bits, ...

so, long story short: you can't unless you want to build an agent!

EDIT: I want to add: Integer.Size gives you the size of an "int", not the size of an "Integer" object!!!